# Laravel route pages with sidebar content

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a Laravel blog, the routing works in a way that every page has it's own `Route::get('params')`.

This works fine and I can send the specific content to each page as needed.

The problem is that I'm trying to also send the sidebar content but I'm trying to prevent writing the same code over and over like this:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $sidebarContent = Photo::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(9)->get();
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

    return View::make('index')->with('sidebarContent', $sidebarContent)
                              ->with('posts', $posts);
});

Route::get('about', function()
{
    $sidebarContent = Photo::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(9)->get();

    return View::make('about')->with('sidebarContent', $sidebarContent);
});
```

What's the best way to do this? Is the following the way I should approach it?

```
Route::group(array(), function()
{
    $sidebarContent = Photo::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(9)->get();

    Route::get('/', function($sidebarContent)
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

        return View::make('index')->with('posts', $posts)
                                  ->with('sidebarContent', $sidebarContent);
    });

    Route::get('about', function($sidebarContent)
    {

        return View::make('about')->with('sidebarContent', $sidebarContent);
    });

});
```

Comment: You need to read up on View Composers - http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers

Comment: Would you say this is a good solution? http://brianretterer.com/laravel-composers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do something like this. :)

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'Controller@index'));
Route::get('user', array('uses' => 'Controller@about'));

class Controller extends BaseController{

    protected $sidebarContent;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->sideBarContent()
    }
    public function index(){
        $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return View::make('index')->with('sidebarContent', $this->sidebarContent)
                              ->with('posts', $posts);
    }
    public function about(){
        return View::make('about')->with('sidebarContent', $this->sidebarContent);
    }
    public function sidebarContent(){
        $this->sidebarContent = Photo::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(9)->get();

    }
}
```